# can not make responsive in bootstrap+magento

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magento

I'm new to magento and I tried to add twitter bootstrap to magento mysite. But it is not works.

this is the structure  of the project.

[image: structure]

This is the local.xml file

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
        <reference name="head">

        <!-- Adding jquery and twitter-bootstrap-files -->
        <action method="addJs"><script>1.7.2.jquery.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>bootstrap.js</script></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap-responsive.css</stylesheet></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/media.css</stylesheet></action>
         </reference>
     </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `root` and `head` references should be used separately.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root"></reference>
    <reference name="head">

    <!-- Adding jquery and twitter-bootstrap-files -->
    <action method="addJs"><script>1.7.2.jquery.min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>bootstrap.js</script></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap-responsive.css</stylesheet></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/media.css</stylesheet></action>
     </reference>

</default>
```

Comment: what is not getting included, css or js Or both?

Comment: Moreover, is the `master` selected as `skin` in `system >> configurations>> Design` in the Theme tab?